# Friendship has_many through model with multiple status'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Currently my User model has the following code:

```
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => { status: 'accepted' }
  has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => { status: 'requested' }
  has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => { status: 'pending' }
```

And my Friendship model is as follows:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

  def self.request(user, friend)
    unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user_id: user, friend_id: friend)
      transaction do
        Friendship.create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
        Friendship.create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
      end
    else
      return "failed"
    end
  end

  def self.accept(user, friend)
    unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user_id: user, friend_id: friend)
      transaction do
        accepted_at = Time.now
        accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
        accept_one_side(friend, user, accepted_at)
      end
    else
      return "failed"
    end
  end

  def self.accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
    request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
    request.status = 'accepted'
    request.accepted_at = accepted_at
    request.save!
  end
```

When I try to run my cucumber tests, however, I am getting this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.status: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "users"."status" = 'accepted' AND "friendships"."user_id" = ? (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I think that this means it is trying to only include inside in for example pending_friends, users which have the attribute status = "pending", where it should actually be including users who belong to friendships which have attribute status = "pending"

Is this right? How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to the following and this works:

```
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :accepted_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :conditions => {status: 'accepted'}
  has_many :requested_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :conditions => {status: 'requested'}
  has_many :pending_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :conditions => {status: 'pending'}
  has_many :friends, :through => :accepted_friendships
  has_many :requested_friends, :through => :requested_friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :pending_friends, :through => :pending_friendships, :source => :friend
```

If anyone has a different approach without having to create accepted_friendshis, requested_friendships, and pending_friendships, however, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

`status` is a column for `friendships` table.

So when you are writing the code, then mention the table name or else it will take the table of the Current model.

```
has_many :friends, -> { where  "friendships.status = 'accepted'" }, :through => :friendships
```

Comment: rails 4 says "friendships.status = 'accepted'" is deprecated so I tried doing it by replacing that with {:friendships.status = 'accepted'} and this doesnt work because :friendships symbol doesnt have .status method

Comment: @delisdeli, Please check my updated answer. hope, it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation on use of `:conditions` with `has_many`, but based on the error that's being generated, I gather that the conditions specified are assumed to apply to the model that is subject of the `has_many`, not the target model or the model `through` which it is being reference.