# Rails 4: Request view only access to users records (Self-Referential)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ember.js

My goal is to give users a way to send requests to share there records with a user with director role and also the director requesting access. So after some investigation, I realized the setup was very similar to how social media platforms send friend requests. However the requests would be one sided for viewing records.

User A wants to share his 'records' with User B who has the managerial type role.

I have concluded this has to do with making a table called 'Requests' at which has states of [pending, accepted]. Maybe another state for sent?

So far I came up with

```
 rails g model request user:reference status:string
```

Model Files

```
 class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
 end


 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...

   has_many :students
   has_many :requests
   has_many :accepted_requests, :class_name => "Request", -> { where(requests: {status: 'accepted'})
   has_many :pending_requests, :class_name => "Request", -> { where(requests: {status: 'pending'})
   has_many :sent_requests, :class_name => "Request", -> { where(requests: {status: 'sent'})

   ...
 end
```

Ember CLI Model (User)

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  requests: DS.hasMany('request')
  students: DS.hasMany('student', {inverse: true});
});
```

A couple good resources I found but wasn't sure how to implement as one-sided.

[Friendship has_many through model with multiple status'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755890/friendship-has-many-through-model-with-multiple-status)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Overall I want the user role of directors to be able to query

```
 User.where(role: 'director', email: 'user@example.com').first.students -> Access to any records of the following users who accepted the request.
```

Then also access to

```
 @user.pending_requests (owned by user that received the request)
 @user.accepted_requests (possibly seen on both sides, so regular users can also delete accepted requests)
 @user.sent_requests (owned by user who sent request).
```

Anybody guide me to the next step or missing parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some ironing out and lots of manipulation I finally got my answer.

Migration

```
rails g model director_id:integer student_id:integer accepted:boolean
```

Request Model

```
belongs_to :director, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User'
```

User Model

```
has_many :requests, foreign_key: :director_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :received_requests, foreign_key: :student_id, class_name: 'Request', dependent: :destroy
has_many :directors, through: :received_requests, source: :director
has_many :students, -> { where  "requests.accepted = true" }, through: :requests, source: :student
```

Now you can create request and can use **@user.students** or **@user.directors**
The students only show up until accepted is true.

Director is only one that has access to sending requests and can see his requests through **@user.requests** and a student can see his current requests through **@user.received_requests**

Here is what I had for the user model in Ember.

```
directors: DS.hasMany('user', {inverse: 'students'}),
students: DS.hasMany('user', {inverse: 'directors', async: true}),
requests: DS.hasMany('request'),
receivedRequests: DS.hasMany('request', {async: true}),
```